# How to implement an autocommand that deletes a buffer when it's being hidden and when it hasn't been modified in the last N seconds?

Tags: buffers, autocmd, error, hidden-buffers

I'm trying to implement a simple autocommand, which deletes a buffer when it's hidden, with a condition that the file hasn't been modified in the last N seconds. I have the following code in `~/.vim/autoload/tools.vim`:

```
function tools#TimeSinceModified(file)
  return localtime() - getftime(a:file)
endfunction

let s:delete_buf_after_s = 1800

function tools#DeleteBuffer(bufnr)
  if !&modified && tools#TimeSinceModified(bufname(a:bufnr)) > s:delete_buf_after_s
    execute 'bdelete' a:bufnr
  endif
endfunction
```

Then, in my `.vimrc`, I have this autocommand:

```
autocmd BufHidden * call tools#DeleteBuffer(expand("<abuf>"))
```

This doesn't work, however. The buffer isn't deleted, and the editor prompts the following error whenever a buffer is being hidden:

```
Error detected while processing function tools#DeleteBuffer:
line    2:
E937: Attempt to delete a buffer that is in use
```

Is there some way of getting around this error? How can I get this functionality to work?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `:bdelete`? If you mean to force close the buffer even if it has changes since it was last saved then just add `!` after `:bdelete`.

Comment: @BLayer Yes, I did read the documentation for `:bdelete`. I think in this case the command without `!` should be sufficient since we're checking that the `modified` flag is `0`, so there shouldn't be any unsaved changes. I also tried `bdelete!` instead of `bdelete` in the function, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I wonder if the fact that tis is during the bufhidden autocommand is the issue. Maybe try using a short timer to run the bdelete?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That might be the problem. I currently have `hidden` option set, so this is triggered everytime a buffer is hidden. But do you know if there is any some other way of achieving the similar functionality I described before? Maybe setting `nohidden` and setting the `bufhidden` option for buffers?

Comment: I would try starting a timer, either in the function or in the autocommand. Honestly, though, i wouldn’t worry about deleting buffers this way unless there’s some particular reason to.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble My motivation here is that I often notice I have quadrillion hidden buffers, e.g. after I've executed `:vimgrep` and I've been checking the results. I would like have some of those unneeded buffers automatically deleted. I don't quite understand how the timer would help here, but as you suggested that I tried replacing the execute `bdelete` with `timer_start(1000, '{timer_id -> 'execute "bdelete!"'})`, but it seems the timer never triggers. Clearly I don't understand how this timer works in Vim. :D

Comment: `expand()` returns string. You really(!) should perform explicit conversion to number (otherwise `bufname()` could be confused). BTW. I prefer purging buffer list manually, no timers or autocommands involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a timer to avoid messing with the buffer during the `BufHidden` event; something like

```
function tools#DeleteBuffer(bufnr)
  if !&modified && tools#TimeSinceModified(bufname(a:bufnr)) > s:delete_buf_after_s
    call timer_start(100, {_ -> execute('bdelete '.a:bufnr)})
  endif 
endfunction
```

We have to use the `execute()` function here because a lambda-body is an expr1 (`:help lambda`), and that also means we have to do our own string concatenation.

A cleaner solution would be to start the timer in the autocommand (which makes  the function stand on its own, to me):

```
autocmd BufHidden * call timer_start(100, {_ -> tools#DeleteBuffer(expand("<abuf>"))}
```

But I worry about the `expand("<abuf>")` not working inside the lambda at that point, and I don't have a workaround yet.